# Is there a way to split an Excel spreadsheet into different files by row value?

Tags: excel, vba, split

I have a large Excel sheet that contains individual valuation reports for different clients all combined into one giant sheet. I need to split this giant sheet into individual report files per client, and then convert to pdf.

I can't split by number of rows because it varies widely.

However, '[SUMMARISED]', and an image of a pie-chart appears on every row preceding each new individual report. This means that the row preceding '[SUMMARISED]' is the break point.

Can I split the data in this sheet based on this word?

[Net Asset Value is the last row of the previous report, '[SUMMARISED]' is the start of a new one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZQMT.png)

'[SUMMARISED]' is in column A

[Top part of the Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw99C.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RUgK.png)

[Debug error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bnUw.png)

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What have you tried? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your post with code you have tried and highlight specific issues you're facing

Comment: To help you in your research: You can loop down the first column keeping two indexes (`report_begin` and `report_end`). Then copy the report into a newly added workbook, which you then save and close. You need to look up "looping", "how to reference ranges", "how to add, save and close a workbook"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448658/is-there-a-way-to-split-excel-spreadsheet-by-row-value

Comment: Does "[SUMMARISED]" also exist at the beginning of the sheet, which cannot be seen in your picture? After opening of a new workbook and copying the necessary range, it should be saved, i suppose, and then close. What name to be used for the workbook? I can see on the next row, following [SUMMARISED] something which could be used, I think. The value of cell in B27 would be OK? If yes, where such a data is kept in the not visible sheet portion? I mean, for the first new workbook...

Comment: Can you edit your question and place a picture showing the top side of the initial worksheet? I would like to see where from to extract the first newly created workbook name...

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes a '[SUMMARISED]' string also exists at the top of the sheet. I've added a picture of the top part of the file.

Comment: OK. I will adapt the code to use the values on B down two rows and make it save to pdf. But take care: **An empty row must exist on top of the sheet to be processed**. I can adapt the code to avoid an error, but like it is it will work if such an empty row will exist...

Comment: Now I have something urgent to finish. I will adapt the code in about an hour...

Comment: Alright, thank you sir

Comment: @Dubem: Please, test the updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testSplitSheetContentSumm()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, count As Long
 Dim rng As Range, strSearch As String, sumCell As Range, startRow As Long
 Dim firstFAddress As String, wbName As String, k As Long, strPath As String
 
 strSearch = "[SUMMARISED]"
 Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your sheet
 strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
 lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 
 Set rng = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
 
 'for speed optimization______________________
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 '____________________________________________
 
 startRow = 1
 Set sumCell = rng.Find(What:=strSearch, After:=sh.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues)
 If Not sumCell Is Nothing Then
    firstFAddress = sumCell.Address
    wbName = sumCell.Offset(2, 1).Value
    'correct the workbook name from ilegal characters
    wbName = Replace(Replace(wbName, "/", "-"), """", "")
    Do
        k = k + 1
        If k = 1 Then GoTo Over
        count = count + 1 'how many files has been saved
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add: Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
        sh.Range(sh.cells(startRow, 1), sh.cells(sumCell.Row - 1, sh.UsedRange.Columns.count)).Copy _
                                                                    Destination:=ws.Range("A1")
        startRow = sumCell.Row
        'saving the workbook:
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'to avoid the screen asking for permition to overwrite existing
         wb.SaveAs strPath & "\" & wbName
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
          'saving the pdf:
          ws.Activate
          ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                    strPath & "\" & wbName & ".pdf"
         
        wb.Close False
        wbName = sumCell.Offset(2, 1).Value
        wbName = Replace(Replace(wbName, "/", "-"), """", "")
Over:
        Set sumCell = rng.FindNext(sumCell)
        
    Loop While Not sumCell Is Nothing And sumCell.Address <> firstFAddress
    'now, the last part should be saved, too:
     Set wb = Workbooks.Add: Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
        sh.Range(sh.cells(startRow, 1), sh.cells(lastRow, sh.UsedRange.Columns.count)).Copy _
                                                                  Destination:=ws.Range("A1")
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         wb.SaveAs strPath & "\" & wbName
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
          ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                    strPath & "\" & wbName & ".pdf", Quality:= _
                    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
        wb.Close False
 Else
    MsgBox "The word """ & strSearch & """ could not be found..."
 End If
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 MsgBox count & " files have been saved in """ & strPath & """ folder.", _
                                              vbInformation, "Job done..."
End Sub
```

Edited: The problem you faced was generated by the fact that the strings used to build the file names contained ilegal characters. Now, the code replaces `/` with `-` and eliminates `"`. The path where the newly created files will be saved, will be the path of the file to be processed.

Comment: @Dubem: Glad I could help! But do you like that way of workbooks naming? Isn't it a way to take the name from the workbook to be processed? There were some fields you tried covering... Wouldn't they be a clue, from this point of view? But it is your choice. Separated of that, we here when somebody answers our question, tick the cole left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Comment: I've added a link to the top portion of the sheet. There is a '[SUMMARISED]' string at the beginning as well.

Comment: Hello @FaneDuru it's not working as intended. I've attached screenshots.

Comment: At your request I can send you a copy of the workbook.

Comment: @Dubem:  If such an error appear, you must check the variables involved. Moving the mouse over `wbName`, what does it show? Can you share the workbook in discussion? You can use [this](https://easyupload.io/) transfer site...

Comment: The code itself works as expected, but the some customers name contain ilegal characters, not accepted in a file name (`/`, `"` etc.)... I was not inspired and I tested it on my working folder and filled it with more then hundred files. Stopped the code and try finding a checking way without really creating the files... If I know which are the involved ilegal characters I will find a way to escape them.

Comment: @Dubem: I have a different question? Do you also need **the xlsx files to be created**, or **only pdf** and you imagined that it is not possible to save only pdf?

Comment: @Dubem: Please check the updated code. If finally shows a message telling how many pdf files have been created. For the sent workbook, it saved 458 files, in about 9 minutes...

Comment: Success! This is beautiful code, it even saves it as xlsx and pdf which is very useful. Thank you very much @FaneDuru.

Comment: @Dubem: Glad I could help! It looks, sometimes after many iterations, VBA is missing the xlsx extension to some saved workbooks name, even if it sholdn't. The code can be adapted to also specify the extension. Or, if you need to open them, rename adding .xlsx...